# Angular Custom Pipe with Max - Min amount

Tags: html, angular, input, pipes-filters

So I am trying to create an input for entering in a price, and that input is being filtered with a pipe. Different prices are being received from an API with JSON info.

So for example, If I enter in the price '$300', the results with have each flight that is $300 and below.

I am really bad at writing pipes :( So far the pipe I have attached to it so far filters the input to a degree but I have no clue of how to make it conditional.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-get-json?file=app%2FfilterPipe.ts

```
   <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<button (click)="onClick()">Send Request</button>

<div>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term">
<p>Result:</p>
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let group of displayItems">
    {{group.departure.city}}
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let flight of group.fares  | filter: term">
        {{flight.price.amount}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here's the Pipe Logic -->

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'filter'
    })
    export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(items: any, term: any): any {
        if (term === undefined) return items;

        return items.filter(function(item) {
          for(let property in item){

            if (item[property] === null){
              continue;
            }
            if(item[property].toString().toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())){
              return true;
            }

           }
          return false;
        });
      }

    }
```

Comment: Please add the essential part of the code directly to the question instead of only linking to an external resource.
What is the actual behavior, what is the expected behavior?

Comment: I added the code I used to the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your filter pipe as below

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(items: any, term: any): any {
    if (term === undefined) return items;   
    return  items.filter(t=>t.price.amount <= term);;
  }

}
```

and **[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-get-json-mcczew?file=app%2FfilterPipe.ts)**

Comment: Dude, I love you. I really have to get better with my programming ah. Thanks.